# format list depending on number of items in it

Tags: python, dynamic, format

I know there has to be a simple way to do this without importing a module but I can't find it.

I want to be able to keep the same format no matter how many items there are in my list. So, for every item in my list, it will add another {:^3}.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print("| {:^3}{:^3}{:^3}{:^3}{:^3}\n".format(*list))
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `"| "+"".join("{:^3}" for _ in list).format(*list)` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using a `"".join` function along with a list comprehension, which does something to each item in an array and then gets a string representation of the array.

```
>>> print("| " + "".join(["{:^3}".format(x) for x in list]) + "\n")
|  1  2  3  4  5
```

This applies `"{:^3}".format(x)` to every item in `list`, where `x` is the current item. It then uses `"".join` on this to get the list items as a string with no delimiter, for example:

```
>>> "".join(["1", "2", "3"])
'123'
```

One other note: You shouldn't be using a variable called `list` because `list` is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: Your example is wrong.  You can't join anything but strings.  If you do `"".join([1, 2, 3])`, you get `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`

Comment: @zondo Oops, fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: When using `.join()`, a list comprehension is more efficient than a generator.

Comment: @zondo Just tested that using `timeit`, and it is indeed 0.7 secs faster. Didn't know that, thank you! Why is it faster to use a list comprehension?

Comment: @Fujtaj No problem. If an answer has helped you, please remember to accept it!

Comment: @zondo and need two more characters. Performance increase is so low, that doesn't cost it.

Comment: I believe that it is faster because `.join()` needs to know how much memory to allocate.  A generator expression needs to be evaluated in order to know how much memory to allocate, so with a generator expression, it needs to be iterated through twice, but a list has already been evaluated, so it doesn't need to be re-evaluated to find how much memory it takes up.

Comment: @germn: 0.7 seconds doesn't seem _so low_ to me, and I don't see that two more characters is really a *cost*.

Comment: @zondo i got less 0.01 difference for 10000 operations: `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

use_list = timeit.timeit(lambda: "| " + "".join(["{:^3}".format(x) for x in lst]) + "\n", number=10000)
use_gen = timeit.timeit(lambda: "| " + "".join("{:^3}".format(x) for x in lst) + "\n", number=10000)

print(use_list, use_gen)`

Answer (score 0):

The `join` function in python is incredibly useful especially for things like this:

`("| "+"".join(["{:^3}" for _ in list]) + "\n").format(*list)`